# Express JS render webpage on a new tab

Tags: node.js, express

I have a code which uses nodeJS for a web app using ExpressJS. A sample of the code which redirects the user to a webpage is:

```
app.post('/accept',(req,res)=>{
     res.render("home");
});
```

The code works fine and redirects the user to the said page, but I want that to happen on a new tab, as in it will redirect the user to the "home" page on a new tab. How do I do that?

Comment: You can not open a tab from server-side/ExpressJS perhaps you can open from front-end like `<a href="/home" target="_blank">`

Answer (score 1):

Your script is server side and makes a response to the client. You can't define there to open a new tab. So you have to handle that in your frontend via javascript.